# Android Dev: using textAppearance or textSize with an attribute string throws resource not found exception

Tags: android, android-layout

So the issue is, when using textSize or textAppearance that is define with an attribute string (ex. android:textAppearance="?attr/font_small") throws a resource not found exception. Any help with this would be much appreciated :)

UPDATE:

Here are my style and attribute definitions:

Styles -

```
<style name="FontSize">
</style>

<style name="FontSize.Small">
    <item name="font_small">14sp</item>
    <item name="font_medium">20sp</item>
    <item name="font_large">26sp</item>
    <item name="font_xlarge">32sp</item>
</style>

<style name="FontSize.Medium">
    <item name="font_small">20sp</item>
    <item name="font_medium">26sp</item>
    <item name="font_large">32sp</item>
    <item name="font_xlarge">38sp</item>
</style>

<style name="FontSize.Large">
    <item name="font_small">26sp</item>
    <item name="font_medium">32sp</item>
    <item name="font_large">38sp</item>
    <item name="font_xlarge">44sp</item>
</style>
```

Attribute def -

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FontStyle">
        <attr name="font_small" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_medium" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_large" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_xlarge" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.baseText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item> 
</style>
```

And use this in your TextView:

`android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.baseText"`

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe ?attr/font_small is a valid argument unless you have explicitly declared it in the attr.xml file. use a dp value with textSize for ex:

```
android:textSize = "24dp"
```

or use the following with textAppearance:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

with large , medium or small according to your need.

Comment: Yes I do have it defined. I'll update with example and let me know if it is correctly defined